# How can I get totals for specific columns in table in a tableau

Tags: visualization, tableau-desktop

I have around 7 columns. I am using Totals from Analysis in the Dashboard for the table.

When I tried Totals, I am getting totals for each column. But I want 2, 3,5 column totals only.

Please help me.

Comment: Please follow the rules here, its community where we help each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the totals apply for all columns, but you can fix that using a little trick:
[image]

Comment: Good, please mark the answer "solved" it will help others also

Comment: #Debayan Thank you so much for your help. I am not sure where to mark the answer as "solved". My question is solved now, thanks :)

Comment: just look at the top left corner of my answer, click the GREEN tick